# Talking to Eurotherm 2416 temperature controller over modbus rs232

Tags: arduino-uno, modbus, rs232

I am trying to implement the modbus library written by smarmengol to read process values and to set new setpoints (e.g. temperature) on a Eurotherm controller. The Arduino sketch looks like this:

```
/**
 *  Modbus master example 2:
 *  The purpose of this example is to query several sets of data
 *  from an external Modbus slave device. 
 *  The link media can be USB or RS232.
 *
 *  Recommended Modbus slave: 
 *  diagslave http://www.modbusdriver.com/diagslave.html
 *
 *  In a Linux box, run 
 *  "./diagslave /dev/ttyUSB0 -b 9600 -d 8 -s 1 -p none -m rtu -a 1"
 *  This is:
 *      serial port /dev/ttyUSB0 at 9600 baud 8N1
 *      RTU mode and address @1
 */

#include <ModbusRtu.h>
#include <SoftwareSerial>

SoftwareSerial mySerial (3,5);

uint16_t au16data[16]; //!< data array for modbus network sharing
uint8_t u8state; //!< machine state
uint8_t u8query; //!< pointer to message query

/**
 *  Modbus object declaration
 *  u8id : node id = 0 for master, = 1..247 for slave
 *  u8serno : serial port (use 0 for Serial)
 *  u8txenpin : 0 for RS-232 and USB-FTDI 
 *               or any pin number > 1 for RS-485
 */
Modbus master(0); // this is master and RS-232 or USB-FTDI

/**
 * This is an structe which contains a query to an slave device
 */
modbus_t telegram[2];

unsigned long u32wait;

void setup() {
  // telegram 0: read registers
  telegram[0].u8id = 1; // slave address
  telegram[0].u8fct = 3; // function code (this one is registers read)
  telegram[0].u16RegAdd = 1; // start address in slave
  telegram[0].u16CoilsNo = 1; // number of elements (coils or registers) to read
  telegram[0].au16reg = au16data; // pointer to a memory array in the Arduino

  // telegram 1: write a single register
  telegram[1].u8id = 1; // slave address
  telegram[1].u8fct = 6; // function code (this one is write a single register)
  telegram[1].u16RegAdd = 2; // start address in slave
  telegram[1].u16CoilsNo = 250; // (Setpoint) number of elements (coils or registers) to read
  telegram[1].au16reg = au16data+4; // pointer to a memory array in the Arduino

  Serial.begin(9600);
  master.begin( &mySerial, 9600); // baud-rate at 9600

  master.setTimeOut( 5000 ); // if there is no answer in 5000 ms,roll over
  u32wait = millis() + 1000;
  u8state = u8query = 0; 
}

void loop() {
  switch( u8state ) {
  case 0: 
    if (millis() > u32wait) u8state++; // wait state
    break;
  case 1: 
    master.query( telegram[u8query] ); // send query (only once)
    u8state++;
    u8query++;
    if (u8query > 2) u8query = 0;
    break;
  case 2:
    master.poll(); // check incoming messages
    if (master.getState() == COM_IDLE) {
      u8state = 0;
      u32wait = millis() + 1000; 
    }
    break;
  }
   Serial.print(au16data[O]);

  au16data[4] = analogRead( 0 );

}
```

I can read process values with telegram[0] very well (temperature and/or setpoint), but I cannot change the setpoint with telegram[1]. If I run the code, it puts the current temperature to serial monitor but resets manually changed setpoints to zero. Where is the error? Should I write the value for the setpoint as HEX or DEC? What does the last command do actually?

Thank you!

Comment: 1) telegram[1].u16CoilsNo = looks like this must be 1 NOT 250 (writing single 16 bit register); 2) are you writing to the same register / setpoint you read in telegram[0]? if so why u16RegAdd address is different?

Comment: @Flanker You are right, it must be 1 (single register) and not 250. The solution for my problem was to set `au16data[4]` to a fixed value, e.g 250, or something like that. I think that `au16data[4]` can be set interactively by sending any number thru a hardware serial, since `analogRead(0)` is Rx on Arduino. The start address for setting (writing) a setpoint is 2 and 1 for reading of the same value (setpoint). That is why `au16RegAdd` differs.Thank You for an answer!!

Answer (score 1):

You could also take a look at this github project:
https://github.com/ukos-git/arduino-eurotherm2416

It is specifically designed for the purpose you ask for. 
It basically includes Module named Temperature and a possibility to set or read it:

```
Temperature.set(100)
t = Temperature.getTemperature()
```

Look at https://github.com/ukos-git/arduino-eurotherm2416/blob/master/app/app.ino.